# Properly Handle "Connection reset by peer" in C#

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I'm building the `c#` example here https://github.com/coolaj86/fizzbuzz/blob/master/tcp-echo-csharp/Main.cs and running it against `netcat`.

When I exit `netcat` with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> it closes the socket and I get

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection reset by peer
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndReceive (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at echo.AsynchronousSocketListener.ReadCallback (IAsyncResult ar) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

In other languages I've used, the FIN is represented as a read of 0 bytes (or an event called 'FIN' or 'end', etc), but I've modified the example to print out a message for a read of 0 bytes and I see no message.

How to I handle the client closing the connection?

I'm looking for an answer such as "Use `System.Net.Foo.Bar.CloseHandler()` or `System.Net.Foo.Bar.ErrorHandler()`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think there is no way to do it gracefully. Because if connection close properly, you get notification about client disconnection. But interrupting program execution by CTRL + C isn't this case. So I advise you just handle exception to workout this problem.

Comment: That's the question I'm asking. How do I handle the exception? Where does the try/catch or Error event callback go?

P.S. netcat exits gracefully with ctrl+c. In other languages I get the end/fin/close/0-bytes-read event.

Comment: if (bytesRead > 0) {
     //recieved some data, work it out
  }
else
{
   //connection closed make a clean up
}

This is actually done in code that you linked in your question. You could get a exception at client.EndRecieve so make a try/catch block here.

Comment: Is there a way to check that the client is still open before calling EndReceive? Or a callback that fires when the client closes?

Comment: I think no, accordingly this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wtt64b.aspx (See notes) if you get SocketException you should check SocketException.ErrorCode. Check this out http://read.pudn.com/downloads135/sourcecode/internet/webserver/576119/Net/Net/HTTP/Server/HTTP_Session.cs__.htm